# How to compile executable for both pre-4.1 and android 5.0?

Tags: android, c++, executable, android-5.0-lollipop, pie-chart

Android 5.0 supports only PIE executables. AFAIK if i compile code with `android-16` platform version and add PIE-related compile and link flags executable will not work at android 4.0. How to compile executable for both pre-4.1 and 5.0 (PIE)?